# Explicit bounds from Tao's result on Collatz conjecture

Tags: fourier-analysis, asymptotics, collatz-conjecture

A [new preprint by Terry Tao](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.03562) has recently appeared and has established some interesting results regarding the topic of Collatz conjecture. I will not cite the precise result, but rather an equivalent formulation which Tao notes in his Remark 1.4:

> For any $\delta>0$ there exists a constant $C_\delta$ such that $\mathrm{Col_{min}}(N)\leq C_\delta$ for all $N$ in a subset of $\mathbb N+1$ of logarithmic density at least $1-\delta$.

My question concerns whether anything is known about the rate of growth of $C_\delta$ as $\delta\to 0$. I will pose two specific questions in that regard. The first one I imagine might have been known before Tao's recent result.

> Are there any values of $\delta<1$ for which an *explicit* upper bound for $C_\delta$ is known?

The second essentially asks if anything sort-of-explicit can be deduced from Tao's result.

> Is the function $N\mapsto C_{1/N}$ upper bounded by a computable function?

(Note that I don't think the answer is "obviously yes" from mere existence of $C_\delta$, since checking that a particular value works seems to be $\Sigma^0_3$ (there exists $N_0$ such that for all $N>N_0$ there exists $M$ such that in $M$ steps at least $1-\delta$ of numbers below $N$ go below $C_\delta$) and is not obviously any lower)

Comment: In v2 of the arXiv preprint, there is more detail, including fairly explicit dependence on $\delta$.

Comment: @BorisBukh That indeed seems to be the case! This certainly answers the second question. Judging from the content of the remark, Tao himself has not performed the explicit computation of any of the constants, so this leaves the first one open. Would you mind leaving your observation in an answer? If no other answer arises, I will award yours the bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In v2 of the arXiv preprint, there is more detail, including fairly explicit dependence on $\delta$.

Comment: "more detail" -- for instance?